# Can I play a first turn Simic Growth Chamber to have 3 mana available in the second turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Using a card like [Simic Growth Chamber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSimic%20Growth%20Chamber%5d) (there are others for other colour combinations) in the first turn and a "normal" land in the second, can I have 3 mana available in the second turn?

> Simic Growth Chamber enters the battlefield tapped.
>
> When Simic Growth Chamber enters the battlefield, return a land you control to its owner's hand.
>
> Tap: Add {G}{U}.

Can I really play this card without any land on the battlefield?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. If you play [Simic Growth Chamber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSimic%20Growth%20Chamber%5d) without any other lands in play, you still must return a land you control to its owner's hand ... which happens to be the Simic Growth Chamber itself. So while it is legal, it is not useful to play it the first turn.

Comment: There are some combo decks that use the bouncelands bouncing themselves to take advantage of "land enters the battlefield" triggers. I'm not sure if any of them can go off on turn 1, though - maybe in Vintage, with Moxen and/or Black Lotuses?

Answer (score 12):

If you rephrase your question to "Can I have 3 mana on turn 2 with a normal land and Simic growth chamber?" the answer is yes, but not if you played Simic Growth chamber on turn 1.

The concept of this lands is to have a land that sort of ramps (gets to a higher count of mana) and filters (gives you different colour options) so the drawback of it is that you lose a turn to play it, it doesn't really advance you on mana per turn, but what it does it ensures that with less cards you have more available mana.

Now there is a deck in modern that abuses the use of this lands by using amulet of Vigor, and this is where you would be able to get to 3 mana on turn 2 with those 2 lands. Turn 1, drop normal land, play amulet of vigor, turn 2 play this land, trigger of the land goes on the stack, trigger from vigor goes on the stack, you choose to resolve the land trigger last, so your land untaps, you tap it for mana (and possibly the other one) and then decide which land to bounce and you have 3 mana in your mana pool.

A deck called Amulet Titan, uses [Amulet of Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmulet%20of%20Vigor%5d) to get these ramp to play [Azusa, Lost but Seeking](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAzusa%2c%20Lost%20but%20Seeking%5d) which allows you to play more lands per turn, which with the right combination would allow you to cast [Primeval Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrimeval%20Titan%5d) on Turn 2/3.

So, as per Glorfindel's answer, No is the answer, but yes it is possible.

Comment: It's possible to play Primeval Titan on turn 2 with these cards? How?

Comment: I would also like to know how you could get Primeval Titan on turn 2... That means 6  mana, not 3...

Comment: Turn 1: land + Amulet of Vigor. Turn 2: Simic Growth Chamber + Azusa. You can play Simic Growth Chamber twice again that same turn, floating the mana, but that only gives you four mana, not six.

Comment: play 1 chamber, float 2 mana, play 2 more vigors, play one more land and you get 6 mana :).....it is an exact 7 card hand. 1 growth, 1 forest, 3 amulets, 1 azusa and 1 prime. Turn 1 Play 1 forest, amulet. Turn 2 play growth, float 2 mana, play azusa, play growth (1st additional land), float 2 mana, play 2 vigors, play growth (2nd additional land), float 6 mana, play Primeval Titan...

Comment: OK, but you need to get a pretty lucky starting hand to pull that off...

Comment: @Glorfindel at no point did I say this was reliable. This is why summer bloom was banned as you would go from 4 azusas to 8/12 azusas. the deck already runs 8 primeval titans as well. having 4 summoning pacts made it very flexible and reliable and summer bloom just made the odds increadibly high to have the combo and possibly pay off.

Comment: Was amulet of vigor text changed by any chance? I'm pretty sure I remember this card having a "put it untapped instead" clause instead of a "untap it", but now I'm looking at it online and I only see the version with "untap it".

Comment: @fireshark519 Wouldn't it be more efficient to play the second turns first vigor before you play the growth?

Comment: @Taemyr you are correct, that opens play for possibly all 4 Titans to be played actually. As you turn 2 play 2nd vigor, drop growth net 4 mana, cast azusa and 3rd vigor, play 1 land cast titan, with titan triggers get tolaria west and another dual land which nets 3 blue from tolaria west and 6 mana from the other land, transmute tolaria west for summoning pact, summoning pact another titan and repeat you might even get enough mana for at least 1 of the titans to attack as well (dont want to do any more math to check the mana xD)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible with a card like [Arboreal Grazer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=461076) (I'm uncertain off the top of my head if there are any other cards that would also work)

Turn 1:

- Play a Forest
- Cast Arboreal Grazer
- Use Arboreal Grazer's ability to put Simic Growth Chamber into play
- Return the Forest to hand

Turn 2:

- Play the Forest again
- Et Voila, 3 mana on turn 2

Comment: Well there's also [fastbond](https://scryfall.com/card/vma/209/fastbond), but that's super banned because of how broken it is.

Comment: @ryanyuyu or simply use Manabond, it is legal in legacy...